# The most efficient way to order a multiset

Tags: combinatorics

The most efficient way to order a multiset

I am provided a random binary sequence together with a ordered multiset. The ordered multiset is created by splitting up the sequence into segments. The multiset has $x$ elements (some are probably duplicates). Every element in the multiset is of size $n$.

What is the most (storage)efficient way of describing the original sequence given the multiset and the original data? In this scenario the multiset itself is costing 0 bits to store. The original data cannot be stored. The original data must be reconstructed via the multiset.

Given an original sequence $s$ and an ordered multiset $m$,

$$g(s,m) = i$$
$$f(m, i) = s$$

> What is the best definition of g,f and i in regards of producing the smallest $i$ in bits of data.

My first and naive thought was rebuilding the sequence by pairing the multiset with a sequence of positions, every position a position in the multiset.

This would take $$((n-1)*x)+1$$ bits of data + the free multiset.

$$(n*x/2+((n-1)*x/4....))$$ and the last position is free since it is the only option.

Can this be improved?

Examples:

original sequence $010100001110010001101001010110111111$

divide the sequence in segments of 3

multiset (unordered, not provided just here for clarity) $010,100,001,110,010,001,101,001,010,110,111,111$

multiset (ordered) $001,001,001,010,010,010,100,101,110,110,111,111$

With the ordered multiset it is trivial to create a sequence of $(12*2)+1$ length that together with the multiset can produce the original sequence

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. It's not at all clear (to me) what you want. Please edit your question to include an example or two of your sequence, how it's split, what the corresponding multiset looks like. And perhaps tell us why you need to solve this problem with efficient space (perhaps at a cost in time). Do use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I've added an example. I'm just curious to know if there are any better way of solving the problem, I do not really know were to start to understand if I'm close to the theoretical limit or if it exists a much better way of order a multiset

Comment: I still cannot figure out what it is you are trying to accomplish. Your "unordered" multiset allows an obvious recreation of the original data (it is the original data with some divisions added in, so just remove the divisions). What is the point of sorting its elements by size? If the number $n$ of elements in the multiset does not exceed the number $m$ of possible values, then you need to store a number of max size $n!$ to recreate the original ordering. If $n > m$, then the number can be smaller than $n!$, I believe.

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify the problem